# Zend Expressive: Как передать в форму объект или массив?

Tags: php, form, doctrine2, zend-framework-2

Здравствуйте!
Как можно передать в форму объект или массив ( в частности в элемент `<select>`) из БД (Zend Expressive + Doctrine)

Форма:

```
public function __construct($name = null)
{
    $name = isset($name) ? $name : 'categories-form';

    parent::__construct($name);
    $this->setAttribute('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
    $this->setHydrator(new ClassMethodsHydrator())->setAttribute('method', 'post');
    $this->add([
        'name'    => 'parent',
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
        'options' => [
            'label' => 'Принадлежность',
            'empty_option' => 'Выберите категорию...',
            'value_options' => [],
        ],
    ]);

    $this->add([
        'name' => 'submit',
        'type'  => 'Submit',
        'attributes' => [
            'value' => 'Сохранить',
        ],
    ]);
}
```

Фабрика:

```
use App\Panel\Form\CategoriesForm;
use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;

class CategoriesFormFactory
{
    /**
     * @param ContainerInterface $container
     * @return CategoriesForm
     */
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        return new CategoriesForm('categories-form');
    }
}
```

Действие:

```
$form = new CategoriesForm();
    if ($request->getMethod() === 'POST') {
        $form->setData($request->getParsedBody());
    }
```

HTML (twig):

```
    <div class="form-group select">
        <label for="{{ form.get('parent').name }}">{{ form.get('parent').label }}</label>
        <select class="form-control" type="{{ form.get('parent').attributes.type }}" name="{{ form.get('parent').name }}">
            {% for option in form.get('parent').options.value_options %}
                <option>{{ option }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class CategoryForm extends Form implements ObjectManagerAwareInterface

private $objectManager;

public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
{
    $this->setObjectManager($objectManager);
}

$this->add([
        'type'  => ObjectSelect::class,
        'name' => 'parent',
        'attributes' => [
            'id' => 'parent',
            'class' => 'select'
        ],
        'options' => [
            'label' => 'Категория',
            'object_manager' => $this->getObjectManager(),
            'target_class'   => Category::class,
            'property'       => 'name',
            'empty_option'   => '== Категория ==',

            'is_method'      => true,
            'find_method'    => [
                'name'   => 'findParentCategories',
                'params' => [
                    //'criteria' => ['status' => 1],
                    'orderBy'  => ['name' => 'ASC'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ]);
```